# having a hard time autosizing background panels for landscape and portrait pics.

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to tile some photo's and obviously some are in landscape and some are in portrait, when I fit my CSS one way it fits landscape when I do it another way it fits portrait. What I need is a box that will fit pics, keep aspect ratio and not hide anything.

I currently have this for html and css:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row event_cover_container">
    <section class="event_cover" style="background-image: url('<%= events.photos.link %>');">
        <div class="">
            <h4><%=events.title %></h4>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
.event_cover_container {
width: 25%;
margin: 5px 5px;
}
.event_cover {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

What is the right way to go about this? I am having some difficulty. Ideally I would like to just change the height and width elements so I can keep things tidy for responsiveness.

If your curious about the inline style for background image, I am pulling in the image using Node.js, this gives me the image.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more looking around and found this article: 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/backgrounds-in-css-everything-you-need-to-know/

Very handy article and I found that I needed to use

`background-size: contain;`

This tells it to maintain the aspect ratio. Then I just gave it a height, 400px in this case. I contained my event within a parent div of 25% so it should scale well!

If I missed or didnt think of something let me know !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "background-size: cover".

```css
.event_cover_container {
margin: 5px 5px;
}
.event_cover {
    background: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/loneliness-wide.jpg') center center; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row event_cover_container">
    <section class="event_cover">
        <div class="">
            <h4><%=events.title %></h4>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: `Cover` makes the photo too big for the parent div. `Contain` maintains the entire picture inside the parent div.